# How can you pass a List<objects that implement an interface> to a method?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstraction

I have a servlet with several methods that get a list of objects from the DAO, turn the list into JSON, and send it back in the response. Every list is made of objects that have a method:

```
public String getAsJson(){...}
```

And the servlet has a bunch of mostly identical methods that look like:

```
private String getUserListAsJson() {
    List<User> userList = this.dao.getUsers();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append('[');
    // loops over the list appending the value of each objects getAsJson()
    builder.append(']');
    return builder.toString();
}
```

The problem is that I have about 6 methods (and growing) that look exactly like that except for different DAO queries. My idea was to create an interface that only had the definition for the `getAsJson()` method, make each bean implement that, and then have another method in the servlet that took objects that implemented that interface. Ended up looking like this:

```
public Interface JsonEnabled {
    public String getAsJson();
}

public class User implements JsonEnabled {
    ....
    @Override
    public String getAsJson() {...}
}

public class TheServlet {
    ...
    private String getUserListAsJson() {
        List<User> userList = this.dao.getUsers();
        return this.getListAsJson(userList);
    }
    private String getListAsJson(List<? implements JsonEnabled> list) {
        // The loop code that is in each method.
    }
}
```

That doesn't compile though. After looking up some documentation from Oracle, you can only have **extends** and not **implements** for generic parameters.  Making all the classes extend from an Abstract Class that just has the getAsJson() method doesn't make sense semantically (the classes are unrelated).

I haven't found a good solution on SO or just googling around, so any help/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: tangental but do you really want to build JSON strings yourself? Suggest using a library like Jackson or something else

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For generic wildcards the keyword `extends` works for both classes and interfaces:

```
private String getListAsJson(List<? extends JsonEnabled> list) { ... }
```

`extends` has slightly different meaning when used for defining generic bounds - it essentially translates to "is, or extends, or implements".

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. I figured that there had to be a way to do this - guess I should go read the documentation again now that you've explained it and see if the docs say the same thing.

Comment: I wish i could give this many many +1s  This is exactly what I needed too, and now I understand what it means as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use

```
private String getListAsJson(List<JsonEnabled> list) { ... }
```

?

Comment: Based in OP code sample, you coudln't pass a `List<User>` parameter to that function.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza nailed it.  Feels like if I am going to go through the trouble of casting each list to a list<JsonEnabled> I might as well just do the JSON there.  I had the same thought though.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I see, thanks. Seems like I've missed this point. However you still can create List<JsonEnabled> and fill it with Users and then pass it too such method.

Comment: @VadymS.Khondar that's an option, but suppose you have your `UserBuilder` class that returns a `List<User>`. Will you need to write a function to convert `List<User>` to `List<JsonEnabled>` and use it everytime to call `getListAsJson` function, what if you have more classes that implements JsonEnabled, that would mean more methods to convert those lists?